# Expression Does Not Produce a Value in Interface ICollection

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

I am working on a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project using Visual Studio 2013/.NET Framework 4.5.  This is in VB.NET.

I'm trying to access TFS data, which I have never done before, so I am using a tutorial.  The tutorial, however, is in C#, so I converted the code.  The C# code compiles and runs without error, but the VB code does not.

C#:

```
public static class ExtensionsMethods
    {
        public static void AddOnUi<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, T item)
        {
            Action<T> addMethod = collection.Add;
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(addMethod, item);
        }
    }
```

VB:

```
Public Module ExtensionsMethods
        Sub New()
        End Sub
        <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
        Public Sub AddOnUi(Of T)(collection As ICollection(Of T), item As T)
            Dim addMethod As Action(Of T) = collection.Add                
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(addMethod, Item)
        End Sub
    End Module
```

The compiler gives an error on the sixth line - Argument not specified for parameter 'item' of 'Public Sub Add(item As T)'

If I add the parameter, like so:

```
Dim addMethod As Action(Of T) = collection.Add(item)
```

I get a different error - Expression does not produce a value

I'm unfamiliar with extension methods.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action(Of T) is a Delegate. **AddressOf** can be used to create one.

```
Public Module ExtensionsMethods
    Sub New()
    End Sub
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
    Public Sub AddOnUi(Of T)(collection As ICollection(Of T), item As T)
        Dim addMethod As Action(Of T) = AddressOf collection.Add
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(addMethod, item)
    End Sub
End Module
```